# Having trouble with extracting specific words from text and saving in list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble with the code. I'm attempting to extract variable names from text (basically from a list) and save them in the list. After executing code, it is still showing list as empty.

```html
list_end = ["=",";",")","("]
list_variable = []

data = ["int z;",
"public data_type getCurrentSteps() {int z = true;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
"public final class a extends b implements Leaderboard {public final int nu;public a(d dVar, data_type i, data_type i2) {super(dVar, i);this.nu = i2;",
"public int getScoreOrder() {return getInteger;",
"arrayList = new ArrayList<>(this.nu);for (int i = 0; i < this.nu; i++)",
"public final class a extends b implements Achievement {public a(d dVar, int i) {super(dVar, i);",
"public int getCurrentSteps() {int z = true;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
"public String getFormattedCurrentSteps() {int z = true;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
"public int getTotalSteps() {int z = true;if (getType() != 1) {z = false;",
"public int getType() {return getInteger();",
"public class a {public static void a(GoogleMapOptions googleMapOptions, Parcel parcel, int i) {data_type k = b.k(parcel);"]

for d in str(data):
    if d.startswith("int") and d.endswith(list_end):
        list_variable.append(d[3:])
```

In the second for loop, it should read data(list) and if any item from list_variable is contained it data(list), it should replace it with "variable".

```html
for a in data:
    for b in list_variable:
        if b in a:
            a.replace("b","variable")
```

Comment: Can you show expected data example?

Comment: You have nothing in `list_variable` so what do you expect to get replaced?

Comment: In your first example, endswith needs an argument of a string or tuple of string, not a list. You can use the any() function instead to check. `if d.startswith("int") and any(d.endswith(x) for x in list_end):` Result: `[' z;']`

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to solve your problem. I will try to suggest a way which is easier to understand and reusable. We will write a custom helper function for `endswith` matching. The custom function is -

```
def custom_endswith(d, list_end):
    for end_pattern in list_end:
        if d.endswith(end_pattern):
            return True
    return False
```

What will this custom function do?

Let's try to understand. The function will take two parameters. First one is the string in which the pattern is searched for. The second parameter is a list of patterns. In our case, it is `list_end`. If any pattern from list_end is matched then the function returns `True` otherwise `False`.

Now, we have to edit the `for loop` part from your first code snippet as follows -

```
for d in data:
    if d.startswith("int") and custom_endswith(d, list_end):
        list_variable.append(d[3:])
```

First of all, it should be `d in data` not `d in str(data)`. The second change is that instead of `d.endswith(pattern_string)`, we will call here our `custom_endswith(d, list_end)`. Because, `endswith` funtion take only one pattern string but we have a list pattern strings.

Now, if we `print(list_variable)`, output is as follows -

```
[' z;']
```

One side note, we can also write `custom_startswith(d, list_start)` just like our `custom_endswith(d, list_end)`.

The benefit of writing custom functions is that we can use these function anywhere in the project at any time with no cost - `write once, use everywhere`

Comment: Thank you so much.  But it only extracted from "z;" for the first item of the list. Where as in my "data", there are multiple variables in my data, I want to extract every variable which start from "int" and end with list_end = ["=",";",")","("]. In this way, I think I can extract all variable names.

Comment: I think I have made mistake in the code. I shouldn't use startwith("int"). It should be like wherever "int" start in string, it should read and extract variable starting after "int" and end with list_end. Even If  "int" is in the middle of the string.